# Python BeautifulSoup Output Two Div Class Values On The Same Line

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse the `slider__image` url value and the `slider__break-name` value in the data below and output the values on the same line seperated by tab, and I want it to do it for all the items on the page.

Currently I can only output just `slider__item` as a whole, but I am having difficulty grabbing the values inside of that class, and iterating them together and outputting them on the same line. I will show example of what I mean below.

Example HTML:

```html
<div class="slider__item">
  <div class="slider__spots-image-name">
    <p class="slider__spots">
      6642 Spots
    </p>

    <div class="slider__image" style="background-image: url(/inventory/front88.png);"></div>
    <p class="slider__break-name">
      Collection543
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="slider__item">
    <div class="slider__spots-image-name">
      <p class="slider__spots">
        233 Spots
      </p>

      <div class="slider__image" style="background-image: url(/inventory/front11238.png);"></div>
      <p class="slider__break-name">
        Collection444
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Desired Output:

```
Collection543   /inventory/front88.png
Collection444   /inventory/front11238.png
```

My Code:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """<div class="slider__item">
    <div class="slider__spots-image-name">
      <p class="slider__spots">
        6642 Spots
      </p>
     
      <div class="slider__image" style="background-image: url(/inventory/front88.png);"></div>
          <p class="slider__break-name">
            Collection543
          </p>
  </div>
<div class="slider__item">
    <div class="slider__spots-image-name">
      <p class="slider__spots">
        233 Spots
      </p>
     
      <div class="slider__image" style="background-image: url(/inventory/front11238.png);"></div>
          <p class="slider__break-name">
            Collection444
          </p>
  </div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data,'html.parser')
results = soup.find_all('div', class_='slider__item')
for x in results:
    print(x.text.strip())
```

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the structure of the items are the same for every item, you can do something like this:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

for item in soup.select('.slider__item'):
    name = item.select_one('.slider__break-name').get_text(strip=True)
    img = item.select_one('.slider__image')['style'].split('(')[-1].split(')')[0]
    print(name, img)
```

Prints:

```
Collection543 /inventory/front88.png
Collection444 /inventory/front11238.png
```